# How to set AWS keys inside a lambda function written in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to set AWS keys inside my lambda function. I need to access AWS SES inside my lambda function so I can send an email. Ive tried setting the environment variables inside the lambda console, but it was unable to find the credentials. Is there a way to set the credentials programmatically?

```
    fun sendEmail(){
        try{
            val client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()


            val request = SendEmailRequest()
                .withDestination(Destination().withToAddresses(EMAIL_TO))
                .withMessage(Message().withBody(Body().withHtml(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_HTML_BODY))
                    .withText(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_TEXT_BODY)))
                    .withSubject(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_SUBJECT)))
                    .withSource(EMAIL_FROM)
                .withConfigurationSetName(EMAIL_CONFIGSET)
            client.sendEmail(request)
            println("Email sent")

        }catch (e: Exception){
            println("Email failed to send with error: ${e.message}")
            println(e.printStackTrace())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- I think the good practice would be to have an iam role (which your lambda would already have) and give that role appropriate access to invoke Amazon SES.
- For example just for the initial testing purpose attach the following policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess` to your lambda iam role. May be later on you can then restrict to only specific actions.
- The policy json is as follows

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @QThompson In that case your the lambda role has privileges to talk to Amazon SES. So you don't need to set the keys in your lambda then

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the credentials using BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)

```
    fun sendEmail(){
        try{

            BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)

            val client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()


            val request = SendEmailRequest()
                .withDestination(Destination().withToAddresses(EMAIL_TO))
                .withMessage(Message().withBody(Body().withHtml(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_HTML_BODY))
                    .withText(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_TEXT_BODY)))
                    .withSubject(Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(EMAIL_SUBJECT)))
                    .withSource(EMAIL_FROM)
                .withConfigurationSetName(EMAIL_CONFIGSET)
            client.sendEmail(request)
            println("Email sent")

        }catch (e: Exception){
            println("Email failed to send with error: ${e.message}")
            println(e.printStackTrace())
        }
    }
```